# SOLR cannot get multicore to function correctly

Tags: solr, tomcat7

This is my 5th `SOLR` install.  I say that after having successfully installed it 4 times prior.  I am installing version 3.5.0 with `Tomcat7` using `Ubuntu 12.04` server.  My issue is that `SOLR` is installed correctly, however is mis-configured somehow.

I have installed `SOLR` in `/var/solr` just as I have always done.  The files that can be seen in that directory are:

```
core0        -- Directory
core1        -- Directory
exampledocs  -- Directory
README.txt   -- File
solr.war     -- File
solr.xml     -- File
```

The contents of `solr.xml` are as follows:

```
<solr persistent="false">

 <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
    <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
 </cores>
</solr>
```

I will provide the 'solr.xml' located in the `/etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/` directory as well.  It's config is as follows:

```
<Context docBase="/var/solr/solr.war" debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">
<Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/var/solr" override="true" />
</Context>
```

And lastly the SOLR home set in the `init.d/tomcat7` file.  I have the variable set as such (at the very top of the file):

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dsolr.home=/var/solr"
export JAVA_OPTS
```

This is very simple configuration, however, I must be missing something.  I can get to `10.x.x.x:8080/solr` But all I see is **Solr Admin** where is should read **Admin Core0 Admin Core1**   Does anyone see anything I am obviously missing?

Comment: It could be that the Core0 and Core1 directory names have `C` in capital letters. However, the `solr.xml` has the `instanceDir`s with a small `c`. ;)

Comment: Good catch .. I have edited my question .. Was a typographical error on my part ..

Comment: have you checked the Tomcat logs to ensure that the Solr instance is starting in the appropriate directory and there are not any obvious errors.

Comment: @PaigeCook --  Could you please Answer, I will accept an vote up  ...  The Directory index could not be created because as you stated, it was looking in the wrong directory that didn't have permissions for writing .. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the Tomcat logs to ensure that the Solr instance is starting in the appropriate directory and there are not any obvious errors.